# How do I make certain regions of of my venn diagram colored and have the rest blank?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, charts, set

For example, make A ∩ B red and everything else white. I've attached an image of my current code and Venn diagram.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("ggVennDiagram")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggVennDiagram)

## Creating a Venn Diagram

# use data frame as input

test = list(A = 1:1,B = 1:1)

# create a Venn diagram and display all sets

ggVennDiagram(test,label = c("none")) + 
scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue",high = "black") + 
theme(legend.position = "none",plot.background = element_rect(fill = "steelblue"),
panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggVennDiagram` isn't designed explicitly to draw diagrams of set membership, but it can be made to do so. If you use the following set-up:

```r
library(ggVennDiagram)
library(ggplot2)

test = list(A = 1:1, B = 1:1)

p <- ggVennDiagram(test,label = c("none")) +
     scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black")) +
     theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, size = 2),
        plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10))

p$layers[[1]]$mapping <- aes(fill = name)
```

Then you can easily specify the membership / non-membership areas like this: first, specify the colors that you want to indicate whether an area is within the set or not:

```r
yes <- "lightblue"
no  <- "white"
```

Now you can draw the sets as follows:

```r
# A
p + scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = yes, B = no, A..B = yes))
```

[image]

```r
# B
p + scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = no, B = yes, A..B = yes))
```

[image]

```r
# A U B
p + scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = yes, B = yes, A..B = yes))
```

[image]

```r
# A n B
p + scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = no, B = no, A..B = yes))
```

[image]

```r
# A' U B'
p + scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = no, B = no, A..B = no)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = yes))
```

[image]

```r
# B'
p + scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = yes, B = no, A..B = no)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = yes))
```

[image]

```r
# A'
p + scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = no, B = yes, A..B = no)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = yes))
```

[image]

Hopefully you have enough here to color any element you want appropriately.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. What about A n B' or (A U B)' ? I'm trying to do them but can't figure it out. Again thank you for the above response!

Comment: @James see my update.